# Sudden drop in number of deleted questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

I study voting patterns in Stack Exchange. When examining deleted posts I noticed a sudden 50% drop in the relative number of deleted questions in February 2015.
The following graph is the result of the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434094/sudden-drop-in-deleted-questions) run in Stack Overflow but the same pattern exists also in Super user.
The yellow line is the weekly sum of deleted questions divided by the total number of questions and the blue line is the same for answers.
What could be the cause for this drop?
[image]

Comment: related: [We should clean up posts that should be improved but haven't been and won't be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293457/839601) (Shog raised concern about this in May 2015)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At one year old, [a whole bunch of questions suddenly become eligible for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). This logic [deletes thousands of questions every week.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why)

So if you're grouping deleted questions *by the month in which they were created*, (and you are) then you'll see a sharp drop at roughly a year ago (this deletion script runs weekly); nothing created after that is eligible yet.